enabling CORS with squid
I live in EU but have a condo in California, and need to access US websites for utilities, bills, insurance, credit unfreeze etc. More and more (most) block ex-US access. I tried several commercial VPNs, but they only work sometimes and the utility webpage in particular is resilient to all VPNs I tried.
I then installed squid on my ec2 instance in us west, and that works beautifully for all of them. I will use it only once a month or so (and turn it off inbetween), so don't expect it to be blacklisted.
However, one of the sites uses a script, and I get this error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
the remote resource at
https://www.blabla.com/api/zipcode?zipcode=XXXXX&[]. (Reason: CORS
header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500.

I added this to the squid.conf per https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-configure-squid-proxy-server-for-cross-origin-resource-sharing/
# Add CORS headers
reply_header_access Access-Control-Allow-Origin all
reply_header_replace Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
reply_header_access Access-Control-Allow-Methods all
reply_header_replace Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,OPTIONS
reply_header_access Access-Control-Allow-Headers all
reply_header_replace Access-Control-Allow-Headers Content-Type

However, I still get the same error message.
Any pointers would be appreciated!
